# Possible ordering of coordinates in a linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

This question was asked on Mathematics Stack Exchange with no answers.

Let $X$ be a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For how many permutations $p$ on $1,...,n$ does there exists $x$ in $X$ with $x_{p(1)}<x_{p(2)}<...<x_{p(n)}?$

We can test each permutation by solving a linear program, but this is time consuming when $n$ is large. Is there a quicker way to solve this problem, or at least approximate the solution?

Comment: In case helpful, for the number of feasible permutations and a comprehensive discussion, see here: https://rangevoting.org/WilsonOrder.html 

"ABSTRACT. We find the maximum, and generic, number of "orderings" of N points in D-dimensional space, provided the points are ordered by increasing distance from another (movable) point, or along a (movable) direction. We also find asymptotic formulas for these quantities, and for Stirling numbers of both kinds, along any ray in the (N,D) parameter-plane"

Comment: Just in case the link above stops working at some point, see:

"Stirling numbers and a geometric structure from voting theory, I.J Good and T.N Tideman 1977."